# pyqgis composer legend error(no print)

Tags: python, print-composer, python-2.7, ppygis

i want to use composer in pyqgis standalone script to create some easy mas using one raster.

my output image is correct i have the image but that code cant print show  the legend in the map,

any idea where i have the wrong in my code for legend?

here the code

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("my/path/", True)
qgs.initQgis()



mapinstance = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
mapinstance.removeAllMapLayers()
raster='raster.tif'
rasterLyr1 = QgsRasterLayer(raster, 'raster')
rasterLyr1.isValid()
rasterLyr1.loadNamedStyle('new.qml')
mapinstance.addMapLayer(rasterLyr1)

#ledend
mapRenderer = QgsMapRenderer()
c = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
legend.model().setLayerSet(mapRenderer.layerSet())
c.addItem(legend)

img = QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
color = QColor(255,255,255)
img.fill(color.rgb())
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
render = QgsMapRenderer()
lst = [ rasterLyr1.id() ] 
render.setLayerSet(lst)
rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)
render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
render.render(p)
p.end()
img.save('out1.png',"png")
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the legend using `legend.update()`, `legend.updateItem()` or `legend.updateLegend()`?

Comment: @Joseph and not change